# Is $\lceil\log n\rceil!$ polynomially bounded?

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis

Considering the definition, $f(n) = O(n^k)$, for some constant $k$. If I choose $k = 100$ and plot, it shows $n^{100} > \lceil\log n\rceil!$  for all $n > 1$.  However, the solutions to *Introduction To Algorithms* (2009) say  that $\lceil\log n\rceil!$ is **not** polynomially bounded. What's going on?

Answer (score 9):

Don't trust plots.

By Stirling's approximation (and dropping the ceilings to avoid notational overload),

$$\begin{align*}
(\log n)! &\sim \sqrt{2\pi \log n}\left(\frac{\log n}{e}\right)^{\log n}\\
  &= \sqrt{2\pi \log n}\, e^{(\log\log n - 1)\log n}\\
  &= \sqrt{2\pi \log n}\, n^{\log\log n - 1}\,,
\end{align*}$$

which grows faster than any polynomial.  But you're not going to see that by plotting versus $n^{100}$ unless you consider values of $n$ big enough that $\log\log n$ is more than about $99$, i.e., roughly $n\geq e^{e^{99}}\approx 10^{10^{42}}$, and you probably didn't consider values of $n$ quite that big, because no plotting software is going to display values like $(10^{10^{42}})^{100}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's choose $n=2^k$, and see if $T(n)=\lceil\log_2 n \rceil !$ is bounded by a "polynomial of $2^k$" i.e. is $O(2^{mk})$ for some constant $m$. That is,  $O({(2^m)}^k)$ for some $m$, or equivalently $O(b^k)$ for some basis $b>1$. In other words, we want to check if $T(n)=T(2^k)$ is bounded by some exponential of $k$.

We have
$$
T(2^k) =
\lceil\log_2 2^k \rceil ! =
\lceil k \rceil ! = k !
$$
However $k!$ grows faster than any exponential. Hence, $T(n)$ is not polynomially bounded w.r.t. $n$.